# Set value first column in row if id match in array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to set checkboxes in a range. The firebase_id array must match column B in the range. If matching? Set row to TRUE. But i'm get some randomly checked checboxxes..

What am I doing wrong..?

```
function setCheckboxIfValueKinguinIdExist() {
      const AS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      const SHEET_TESTING = AS.getSheetByName("Testing");
      
      let get_firebase_items = getSelectedIdsFromFirebase();
      let firebase_ids = get_firebase_items.map(function(item){return item.kinguinId}); // [ '17','2962','9798']
      let last_row = SHEET_TESTING.getLastRow();
     
       
      let values = SHEET_TESTING.getRange("A2:B"+last_row).getValues();
      let row = 1; 
      for(let a in values) {
        let item = values[a][1];

        if(firebase_ids.includes(item) === true){
           SHEET_TESTING.getRange(row,1).setValue("TRUE");
        }   
     
        row++;
      }
    }
```

Comment: The startrow for your data is row two.  Why isn't it the same in your loop?  row=2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function setCheckboxIfValueKinguinIdExist() {
  const AS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const SHEET_TESTING = AS.getSheetByName("Testing");
  let get_firebase_items = getSelectedIdsFromFirebase();
  let firebase_ids = get_firebase_items.map(function(item){return item.kinguinId}); // [ '17','2962','9798']
  var last_row = SHEET_TESTING.getLastRow();
  var values = SHEET_TESTING.getRange("A2:B"+last_row).getValues();
  var row = 1; 
  values.forEach((r,i)=>{
      if(firebase_ids.includes(r[1])) {
      SHEET_TESTING.getRange(i+2,1).setValue("TRUE");
    }   
  });
}
```

Comment: It worked. Now i know why the id's didn't match. Because the ids in the value array are int's while the firebase id's are string's. So i modified if(firebase_ids.includes(r[1])) to if(firebase_ids.includes(r[1].toString())).